# .htaccess OnRewriteRule keeping extension the same

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to change the file shown with php but keep the same extension?
Say, I want to dynamically change a non-php/html file (like a text file) by using an equivalent file with dynamic php.
In my .htaccess file, I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^robots.txt http://domain.com/directory/robots.php [R=301,L]
```

The above code redirects the *robots.txt* request to *robots.php*.
How can I get it to keep the same extension but load the different file?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^robots.txt /directory/robots.php [L]`

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I would mark it as right, but you answered as a comment. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^robots.txt /directory/robots.php [L]
```